# How to pull new data from API using node / electron desktop application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, electron, shopify

I'm creating a private desktop application for my Shopify store and was wondering what the best way to continuously pull new order data down from their API?  While the application is open do I query the API for new orders at a set interval? Is there a way to use webhooks with a desktop application (not a server)?  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need a server to receive webhooks, but if you don't want to manage a server, you can use a serverless solution such as [Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/).

For example, you can do something like the following:

- EventBridge receives your order data through the Shopify webhook.
- The order data is added to an [SQS queue](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).
- Your desktop app connects to the SQS queue to receive the order data.

Here is a tutorial from Shopify that explains this approach:

https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-webhook-events-with-eventbridge

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was not familiar with EventBridge